# Make `last` display year in Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell

Is there any way to get `last` (on Mac OS X 10.11.2) to display a full date (including year)? Right now it displays only day and time:

```
user$ sudo last user | head -n3
user   ttys000                   Fri Jan 15 18:12 - 18:15  (00:03)
user   ttys000                   Fri Jan 15 18:11 - 18:12  (00:00)
user   ttys000                   Fri Jan 15 18:11 - 18:11  (00:00)
```

On other systems, there are options such as `-F` or `-t` to make `last` display the full date, but on the Mac OS X platform, there are only 3 options, none of which have the desired effect: `-t` for tty, `-h` for host, and `-n` for number of lines to display (and `-n` doesn't even work).

Are there any alternatives to this command?

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal, if you use the `man ls` command, you will get the list of available options for `ls` including this one.

> -T  When used with the -l (lowercase letter ``ell'') option, display complete time information for the file, including month, day, hour,
>   minute, second, and year.

Type `q` to exit the manual.

Then try this: `ls -lT`

Comment: Unfortunately, I was asking about the `last` command, which displays a list of last login times; these are not files. I already knew about `ls -T` and `stat`.